# Loading in a space delimited dataset into R without removing spaces in between strings

Tags: r, csv, dataset, delimiter, data-wrangling

I have a big csv file where all the values for a row are in a single cell separated by spaces. This data is a mix of numeric values and strings. When I load in the data it splits up the strings for a single variable in multiple columns.

**Example of data structure:**

```
Survey "SiteNo" "CODE" "Species_name" "Length" "Sex" "Age" "Station" "lonitude" "latitude" "Date" "Weight"  
1 "T 19/11" 45 "MMM" "Gadus Morhua" 80 "U" NA "F5" -7.979 50.837 2011-11-14 4   
2 "T 20/14" 20 "MNE" "Homarus Gammarus" 75 "U" "0" 1 -2.501 50.216 2014-10-02 3
```

where each line is a row (all data for each row in a single cell)

**I need the data to look like:**

| Survey | SiteNo | MMM | Species_name | Length | Sex | Age | Station | lonitude | latitude | Date | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T 19/11 | 45 | MMM | Gadus Morhua | 80 | U | 1 | F5 | -7.979 | 50.837 | 2011-11-14 | 4 |
| T 20/14 | 20 | MNE | Homarus Gammarus | 75 | U | 0 | 1 | -2.501 | 50.216 | 2014-10-02 | 3 |

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using `sep=' '` in `read.table`.

```
r <- read.table('foo.csv', sep=' ')
r
#    Survey SiteNo CODE     Species_name Length Sex Age Station lonitude latitude       Date Weight
# 1 T 19/11     45  MMM     Gadus Morhua     80   U  NA      F5   -7.979   50.837 2011-11-14      4
# 2 T 20/14     20  MNE Homarus Gammarus     75   U   0       1   -2.501   50.216 2014-10-02      3
```

Where

```
str(r)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  12 variables:
#  $ Survey      : chr  "T 19/11" "T 20/14"
#  $ SiteNo      : int  45 20
#  $ CODE        : chr  "MMM" "MNE"
#  $ Species_name: chr  "Gadus Morhua" "Homarus Gammarus"
#  $ Length      : int  80 75
#  $ Sex         : chr  "U" "U"
#  $ Age         : int  NA 0
#  $ Station     : chr  "F5" "1"
#  $ lonitude    : num  -7.98 -2.5
#  $ latitude    : num  50.8 50.2
#  $ Date        : chr  "2011-11-14" "2014-10-02"
#  $ Weight      : num  4 3
```

---

*.csv content*

```
Survey "SiteNo" "CODE" "Species_name" "Length" "Sex" "Age" "Station" "lonitude" "latitude" "Date" "Weight"  
1 "T 19/11" 45 "MMM" "Gadus Morhua" 80 "U" NA "F5" -7.979 50.837 2011-11-14 4   
2 "T 20/14" 20 "MNE" "Homarus Gammarus" 75 "U" "0" 1 -2.501 50.216 2014-10-02 3
```

Comment: when I use read.table it has the same problem of just putting all the data for each row in a single cell as a single variable

Comment: @greentea_678 No clue, I used the data you provided and it worked. Help me to reproduce your problem.